# Pass the Value on Button Click Knockout MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvvm, knockout.js

I need to pass the guid on knock out button click in MVC. but when I try this It showing error on line item.Id line. I am using knockout mvc Master project to do this.can any one please help me on this???

```
<tbody>
    @using (var items = ko.Foreach(m => m.managexmlfiles))
    {
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>@items.Html.Span(item => item.DisplayName)</td>
            <td>@items.Html.Span(item => item.DownloadedDate)</td>
            <td>@items.Html.Span(item => item.UpdateDate)</td>                                    
            <td>@ko.Html.Button("Download", "DownloadFile", "UpdateDatabase", new { Id = item.Id })</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is related to the fact that `item.Id` is a knockout observable, you would access the value by calling `item.Id()`. The line in question would then be:

```
<td>@ko.Html.Button("Download", "DownloadFile", "UpdateDatabase", new { Id = item.Id() })</td>
```